# How would i make a glowing outline in wpf?

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml

[image]
The image is an idea of what i want.

I want to make an glowing outline on a border, this is code i made:

```
<Border x:Name="MainBorder" 
                Background="#161616"
                CornerRadius="10"
                BorderThickness="4"
                BorderBrush="#400F62"
                Opacity="1.0" Margin="10">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#FFAB08EC" BlurRadius="7" Opacity="0.75" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="7"/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
```

but that does not even come close to an glowing outline, how would i do that?

I tried using dropshadow but that does not come close to an glowing outline

And what i expect is a glowing outline?

Comment: Do you want to make a brighter look or a flat angle?

Comment: i want it like this https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1025693064053919818/1035661966703869962/unknown.png

Comment: Have you considered placing a thick rectangle behind the border that uses the blur effect?  if the border needs to be resized it would not be ideal but they could be synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
 <Border Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MainBorder" Height="24"
            Background="#161616"
            CornerRadius="2"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="#400F62"
            Margin="10">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#FFAB08EC" BlurRadius="4" Opacity="1" ShadowDepth="0"/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
```

Mainly, you want to reduce the shadow depth to be right behind your border, not in a different direction.

[image]

Comment: How can i mark this post at solved?